# Chef remote_directory cookbook @recipe_files not found

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've created a simple recipe to copy files from one directory to another on windows.

Recipe:

```
remote_directory 'C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination' do
  source 'C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\source'
  action :create
end
```

However, I'm getting the following error when trying to execute the recipe in --local-mode for the sake of testing the recipe before deploying it on Chef server:

```
PS C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo> chef-client
--local-mode .\copyBinaries.rb [2017-08-08T13:34:03+03:00] INFO: Started chef-zero at chefzero://localhost:1 with repository at C:/chef-repo/chef-repo   One version per cookbook

Starting Chef Client, version 13.2.20 [2017-08-08T13:34:03+03:00] INFO: *** Chef 13.2.20 *** [2017-08-08T13:34:03+03:00] INFO: Platform: i386-mingw32 [2017-08-08T13:34:03+03:00] INFO: Chef-client pid: 10708 [2017-08-08T13:34:03+03:00] INFO: The plugin path C:\chef\ohai\plugins does not exist. Skipping... [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Run List is [] [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Run List expands to [] [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Starting Chef Run for mohammedr [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Running start handlers [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Start handlers complete. resolving cookbooks for run list: [] [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Loading cookbooks [] Synchronizing Cookbooks: Installing Cookbook Gems: Compiling Cookbooks... [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] WARN: Node mohammedr has an empty run list. Converging 1 resources Recipe: @recipe_files::C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb
* remote_directory[C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination] action create[2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Processing remote_directory[C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination] action create (@recipe_files::C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb line 7)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `create` on resource 'remote_directory[C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination]'
    ================================================================================

    Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound
    ----------------------------------
    Cookbook @recipe_files not found. If you're loading @recipe_files from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb

      7: remote_directory 'C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination' do
      8:   source 'C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\source'
      9:   action :create
     10: end
     11:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb:7:in `from_file'

    remote_directory("C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination") do
      action [:create]
      default_guard_interpreter :default
      path "C:\\chef-repo\\chef-repo\\cookbooks\\chef-repo\\recipes\\destination"
      recursive true
      source "C:\\chef-repo\\chef-repo\\cookbooks\\chef-repo\\recipes\\source"
      files_backup 5
      files_owner nil
      files_group nil
      overwrite true
      declared_type :remote_directory
      cookbook_name "@recipe_files"
      recipe_name "C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb"
      mode nil
      owner nil
      group nil
      files_mode nil
    end

    System Info:
    ------------
    chef_version=13.2.20
    platform=windows
    platform_version=10.0.14393
    ruby=ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [i386-mingw32]
    program_name=C:/opscode/chefdk/modules/chef/../../bin/chef-client
    executable=C:/opscode/chefdk/bin/chef-client

[2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers: [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers Running handlers complete [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 09 seconds [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to c:/chef-repo/chef-repo/.chef/local-mode-cache/cache/chef-stacktrace.out [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report [2017-08-08T13:34:12+03:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: remote_directory[C:\chef-repo\chef-repo\cookbooks\chef-repo\recipes\destination] (@recipe_files::C:/chef-repo/chef-repo/cookbooks/chef-repo/copyBinaries.rb line 7) had an error: Chef::Exceptions::CookbookNotFound: Cookbook @recipe_files not found. If you're loading @recipe_files from another cookbook, make sure you configure the dependency in your metadata
```

I've tried searching the internet for a solution regarding this issue, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1):

The [`remote_directory`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_remote_directory.html) resource takes files from the cookbook's `files/` folder.

What you do looks pretty weird to me - you're copying recipes, and you're hardcoding local paths to the cookbook. Better ask a new question including your actual goal. I'm pretty confident that `remote_directory` is not what you want.

Comment: My goal is to copy binaries from one directory to another, let's say release server to a node being managed by Chef Server, or between two directories on the same node. Note: I'm hard coding paths just for the sake of testing.

Comment: What, from a remote server or locally? That's a difference (in the chef implementation). As long as the release server serves them via HTTP, use the `remote_file` resource.

Comment: Currently all our servers are available in our LAN. There are instances that we would like to copy binaries within the same server, and sometimes between two different servers in the same LAN. Nothing is being copied to the cloud.

Comment: You have to implement both and decide, which code to run based on an attribute or a separate recipe that you include in the run list. Start with the one way to receive the files, if you have a specific question then, ask it as a separate one including your code.